# How to mock the useState in rtl test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

this is component

```
const Analytics = () => {
const [isLoading,setIsLoading]=useState(true);

const handleAnnouncementsClick = () => {
navigate('/applications/announcements');
};

return (

<DashboardLayout>
<DashboardNavbar />

{isLoading ? (
     showLoader()
) : (
<>
<Grid container spacing={3}>
<DashboardLeftGrid item xs={12} sm={6}>
  <AnnouncementCard
  ispermission={handleBooleanProp(true)}
  onClick={handleAnnouncementsClick}
data-testid="Announcements"
>
   <HeadingMuiTypography variant="h6">
     Announcements
   </HeadingMuiTypography>
   <DashboardAnnouncements />
  </AnnouncementCard>
</DashboardLeftGrid>
)
}
```

this is unit test case component
if isLoading state become false
then only test case becomes pass or else failing

if i comment isLoading related condition test case becomes pass try to help me out

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import Analytics from './index';
import { testComponent } from 'utils/commonUtils';

describe('Analytics component', () => {

  test('renders Analytics component correctly', async () => {
    render(testComponent(<Analytics />));
    expect(screen.getByTestId(/Announcements/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

});
```

Comment: _Don't_ mock it. Test the _behaviour_, not the implementation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
i tried commenting
{isLoading ? (
     showLoader()
) : (
<>...</>)
then it works 
but i don't want to comment it.

Comment: Who calls `setIsLoading` to change the loading state? I assume it is a async call. This is what you have to mock most probably

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to test that the loader is showing, then trigger whatever sets isLoading to false, then test that the Announcements is visible. And you made your test async, so I assume there is some async logic involved, so you should await this with waitFor (or find)

```
  test('renders Analytics when loading is done, loader otherwise', async () => {
    render(testComponent(<Analytics />));
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByTestId(LoadingComponent).toBeVisible();
    })
    await user.press(screen.getTheButtonThatTriggersTheLoadingToBeDone())

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByTestId(AnnouncementComponent).toBeVisible();
    })
  });
```

I think this should be your starting point